# AttributeError : 'MyFrame' object has no attribute 'sommation'

Tags: python, wxglade

I am making a simple GUI calculateur by using wxGlade.

After creating the GUI through wxGlade and having the code generated,
I modified and entered some particular code so that the calculateur functions like it should be.

Briefly, user need to choose either they are adding, subtracting or multiplying both of the value, entered by the user at the begining, by choosing the  radio button that represents the task that the user want.

By choosing the button addition, the user will select the addition task. Below is the code:

```
def add(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
        self.sommation = True 
        self.moins = False
        self.multiply = False
        event.Skip()
```

The same goes to the subtracting,

```
def moins(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
        self.moins = True 
        self.sommation = False
        self.multiply = False
        event.Skip()
```

and the multiplication

```
def multiply(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
        self.multiply = True
        self.sommation = False
        self.moins = False
        event.Skip()
```

after choosing the task, the user click on a button called calcul to have the results. below is the code for the calcul task :

```
def calcul(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>

        if self.sommation == True :
            self.c = int(self.text_ctrl_1.GetValue()) + int(self.text_ctrl_2.GetValue())
            self.somation == False 
        elif self.moins == True : 
            self.c = int(self.text_ctrl_1.GetValue()) - int(self.text_ctrl_2.GetValue())
            self.moins = False 
        elif self.multiply == True :
            self.c = int(self.text_ctrl_1.GetValue()) * int(self.text_ctrl_2.GetValue())
            self.multiply = False
        self.button_1.SetLabel(str(self.c))
        event.Skip()
```

The problem is that, I keep having the problem of the attribute error cited on the title.

Here is the error:
[image: error message]

p/s this is the full program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: CP1252 -*-
#
# generated by wxGlade 0.6.8 (standalone edition) on Thu Mar 17 07:56:19 2016
#

import wx

# begin wxGlade: dependencies
import gettext
# end wxGlade

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.radio_btn_1 = wx.RadioButton(self, wx.ID_ANY, _("addition\n"), style=wx.RB_GROUP)
        self.text_ctrl_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.radio_btn_2 = wx.RadioButton(self, wx.ID_ANY, _("subtraction"))
        self.text_ctrl_2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.label_1 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, _("="), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.button_2 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.radio_btn_3 = wx.RadioButton(self, wx.ID_ANY, _("multiply"))
        self.button_1 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, _("calcul"))

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.add, self.radio_btn_1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.moins, self.radio_btn_2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.multiply, self.radio_btn_3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.calcul, self.button_1)
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle(_("frame_1"))
        self.SetFont(wx.Font(20, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, ""))
        self.label_1.SetFont(wx.Font(16, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, ""))
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__do_layout
        sizer_1 = wx.GridSizer(3, 5, 0, 0)
        sizer_1.Add((0, 20), 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.SHAPED, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.radio_btn_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 0)
        sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.SHAPED, 0)
        sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.SHAPED, 0)
        sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.SHAPED, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.text_ctrl_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.SHAPED, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.radio_btn_2, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.text_ctrl_2, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.SHAPED, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.label_1, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.SHAPED, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.button_2, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.SHAPED, 0)
        sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.SHAPED, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.radio_btn_3, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 0)
        sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.SHAPED, 0)
        sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.SHAPED, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.button_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.SHAPED, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        sizer_1.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def add(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
        self.sommation = True 
        self.moins = False
        self.multiply = False
        event.Skip()

    def moins(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
        self.moins = True 
        self.sommation = False
        self.multiply = False
        event.Skip()

    def multiply(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
        self.multiply = True
        self.sommation = False
        self.moins = False
        event.Skip()

    def calcul(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>

        if self.sommation == True :
            self.c = int(self.text_ctrl_1.GetValue()) + int(self.text_ctrl_2.GetValue())
            self.somation == False 
        elif self.moins == True : 
            self.c = int(self.text_ctrl_1.GetValue()) - int(self.text_ctrl_2.GetValue())
            self.moins = False 
        elif self.multiply == True :
            self.c = int(self.text_ctrl_1.GetValue()) * int(self.text_ctrl_2.GetValue())
            self.multiply = False
        self.button_1.SetLabel(str(self.c))
        event.Skip()

# end of class MyFrame
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gettext.install("app") # replace with the appropriate catalog name

    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: `MyFrame` has the method `add(self, event)` instead of `addition(...)`. Did you just connected the wrong method to the event?

Comment: actually addition is a variable that i've created to signify that the user want to do the addition

Comment: In your code posted above the attribute `addition` is neither defined nor referenced nor an exception traceback where the attribute is expected. Please post at least the traceback that we can see where the exception occurs.

Comment: pardon me, when i mean addition, it represents sommation.. really sorry for this silly mistake

Comment: So.. is your problem solved or only title is wrong? If the latter please edit the title and also please include full error message. That'd show at which line that problem has occured.

Comment: the problem is not solved yet, and yes i will put the image of the problem if it helps..

Comment: I am no expert on wx but seems like your code doesn't get into add, moins etc. thus it is not creating self.sommation variable. Please check your bindings. You can check if it goes in those methods by putting prints in them.

Comment: you are right; Thanks for the remarks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get this error if someone clicks the calculate button before entering any numbers; since you are only creating the variable in your button handlers.

To avoid this, add `self.sommation = None` to the `__init__` method, so it has a default value.

Comment: Yerp, i just remark this problems. Thanks for the help